# writing and reading into a file in C language

Tags: c, file-io, struct

Recentl I have started learning file I/O in C like fopen fwrite and stuff like that. I have a question regard writing/reading a struct that has pointers to a file. Let's say the struct looks like this

```
  struct {
  int len;
  int* data;
  }intarr;
```

len is the length of the array

data points to a integer array.

Assuming I know what the struct is(so I can read it back later on), I need to write len and data into the file in binary format. But if I only write the struct to the file, only the pointers are saved into the file instead of the content.

My current approach is that I copy the data into a new array,then I write the len and the new array into the file separately.

I am not too sure if my approach is correct or not. If it is correct, how are you supposed to read them back? If not ,what are we supposed to do when we want to write all the content of a struct with pointers into a file so we can read them back later?...
I am still new to programming so if I have said anything wrong,please correct me.

Comment: there is no need to copy, just write the array afterwards then when you read you read first the length then do a fread with that number of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) & [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing). Read also about [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) & [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) .

You could `fwrite` the `len` then the array content:

```
 if (fwrite(&intarr.len, sizeof(int), 1, file)) != 1)
   { perror("write length failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (fwrite(intarr.arr, sizeof(int), intarr.len, file) != intarr.len)
   { perror("write array failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

To read the data back (e.g. after a [rewind(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3.html) or after having `fopen`-ed the `file`), read first the length then allocate and read the array:

```
 if (fread(&intarr.len, sizeof(int), 1, file)) != 1)
   { perror("read length failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 intarr.arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*intarr.len));
 if (!intarr.arr) { perror ("malloc failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (fread(intarr.arr, sizeof(int), intarr.len, file) != intarr.len)
   { perror("read array failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Read also about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and about [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html). Notice that `stdio` file streams maintain a current file position (so data is written in sequence, not overwritten) thant you can query with [ftell(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftell.3.html). Some file streams (like on Linux those above [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s i.e. from [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)) are not seekable.

In practice, you might serialize in a textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/) and/or use a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (e.g. [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/) ....); [textual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) formats are much more portable and easier to debug. And since disk may be a million times slower than CPU it is worth spending some processing time to organize data on disk.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `write(intarr.arr, sizeof(int), ...`? (without the `&`)

Comment: That's  what I have been confused about. When you write into the file the 2nd time, won't it overwrite whatever we write into the file the first time?

Comment: No, follow the links in my answer

Comment: Just saw it. Thank you so much